What to use inside a method instead of ValueTuple?
I have a method with local list of value tuples.
List<(BalanceRateRange range, Rate rate)> arr

And inside foreach I search an item and I want to change a property rate of that item.
arr.First(el => el.range == rate.BalanceRateRange!).rate = rate;

But I get an error:

Cannot modify the return value because it is not a variable.

I understand that this is because (BalanceRateRange range, Rate rate) is a Value type object. So my question is what can I use instead of ValueTuple to group 2 properties together if I don't want to create a separate class for this case (because I need that object only in 1 method)?
UPDATE: after reading 3 answers below my resolution is: this is VERY VERY STRANGE that in 2024 in last version of C# (13??) there is no way to use local mutable reference-typed tuples.

As you know, ValueTuples are immutable. This seems like an X/Y problem. Why are you choosing a ValueTuple, and why are you trying to update it?

@gunr2171 value tuples are not immutable. Their fields are public. Maybe you are confusing them with reference tuples that have read only properties?

Related: Changing the value of an element in a list of structs.

"in last version of C# there is no way to use local mutable reference-typed tuples." -- Reference tuples are out of favor. I am not expecting that C# well ever get support for using reference tuples the same way it supports value tuples with parentheses notation. For me reference tuples are a thing of the past, and I never use them for new development.

ValueTuples are passed by value, which means the call to First() is returning a copy of the ValueTuple, so setting its property won't do anything. The compiler is warning you that there's no good reason for your code to try to do this, and you're probably expecting a very different behavior from what you'd get if this were allowed to compile.
Technically, you could avoid the compiler error by saving the value tuple into a variable, and then changing the rate on that variable. However, you wouldn't be changing the value of the object in the actual list.
var match = arr.First(el => el.range == rate.BalanceRateRange!);
match.rate = rate;

// prints "False"
Console.WriteLine(arr.First(el => el.range == rate.BalanceRateRange!).rate == match.rate);

There are a number of potential problems with this code, and it's hard to provide a good recommendation without understanding what you're actually trying to do. It's often a good idea to avoid changing state at all, and simply create a transform. For example, instead of changing arr in a loop, you can create a new array that represents the old one with its new rate information:
var newRatesByRange = newRates.ToDictionary(r => r.BalanceRateRange);
var newArr = arr.Select(el => (el.range, newRatesByRange[el.range])).ToList();


You can only modify the entire element of your List, and its element's tuple type is just fine.
Like this:
int index = arr.FindIndex(/* ... */); // same as First, but index
if (index >= 0) // really found? don't forget to check it
    arr[index] = (arr[index].range, rate);

The idea is: you create a new tuple instance, using range part from old instance and new rate. This is equivalent to assigning just new rate to the list element arr[index].

This will work, but this is very inconvinient especially if I have local ValueTuple with for example 10 or more items.

@Andrew — “This will work, but this is very inconvenient, especially if I have local ValueTuple with for example 10 or more items”. Of course, you are absolutely right, but you asked specifically about 2-tuple with concrete types, that can be considered ad-hoc problem. I would hardly advise similar thing even for 3-tuple, instead of effectively partial 2-variants case arr[index] = (arr[index].a, b) or arr[index] = a, (arr[index].b). Why not accept it as the simplest working variant?
And a convenient variant could always be a class { range, rate }. Do you want another answer?

@Andrew — “This will work, but this is very inconvenient, especially if I have local ValueTuple with for example 10 or more items”. And, by the way: if you were interested in many items, you should have asked about a more universal solution, a proper container class, and then I would think about it. However, in the most universal case it looks like a variadic generic. Even for variadic generics, there was a proposal at .NET GitHub community...

This error occurs because when you retrieve a value type from a property or indexer, you are getting a copy of the value, not a reference to the value itself. So the compiler generates an error (CS1612), in order to protect you from mutating a copy that is going to be unceremoniously discarded immediately after the mutation.
You could consider implementing an extension method FirstRef for lists, that returns a reference to the found value, instead of returning a copy of the value:
public static ref T FirstRef<T>(this List<T> source, Predicate<T> match)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(match);
    int index = source.FindIndex(match);
    if (index < 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no matching element.");
    return ref CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(source)[index];
}

Usage example:
arr.FirstRef(el => el.range == rate.BalanceRateRange!).rate = rate;

You can learn here about the ref return statement (C# 7.0), and here about the CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan API (.NET 5).
